# How to use gettimeofday in the kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to use the following code in the kernel module

```
struct timeval now;

gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
```

But getting following error while compiling kernel

```
drivers/media/i2c/ox05b.c:776:17: error: storage size of ‘now’ isn’t known
  776 |  struct timeval now;
      |                 ^~~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of kernel development is that the C library isn’t available. In a kernel module, if you want to know the time, you should use the appropriate [ktime accessor](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html), for example

```c
#include <linux/timekeeping.h>

…

ktime_t now = ktime_get_real();
```